# GLFlatText resolution issue in GLScene

Tags: delphi, opengl, glscene

I have GLFlatText in GLScene application, but I never achieved the satisfactory text resolution with GLFlatText component as can be seen from attached image, red rectangle marked GLFlatText is always blurred and does't give good results especially when you zoom in. But on the other hand blue marked HUD Text is exactly what I want to achieve. Drawback for the hud text is: It always have to be placed on canvas, there is some methods to look like it has depth in 3D with MVPW matrix manipulation in Cadenceer, but I don't prefer that way, cause it may slow down whole rendering of scene.

AFAIU there is not an easy way to get crystal clear text on openGL rendering context if you realy on RC because it has to pass, if there is, many openGL test through OpenGL pipeline.

So, is there a way to get the look of hud text with glflat text component?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var
  _FlatText: TGLFlatText;
begin
...
  _FlatText.Scale.X := 0.06;
  _FlatText.Scale.Y := 0.06;
  (_FlatText.BitmapFont as TGLWindowsBitmapFont).Font.Size := 12;
```

Increase font size and decrease scale.